# What is the right syntax for Optional.orElseThrow in Xtend?

Tags: exception, option-type, xtend

I'm stuck with a simple problem: I have a `java.util.Optional` and want to use the `orElseThrow` method to throw an exception if value is not present. However I cannot figure the right syntax to do this in Xtend. In Java, I would do:

```
Optional<String> host = ... // get from some method
host.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Host is not provided"));
```

But this does not compile in Xtend. The error message in Eclipse is like this (where `MyClass` is the name of my custom class):

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Pair<MyClass, IllegalArgumentException> to Supplier<? extends Throwable>
- no viable alternative at input ')'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
val Optional<String> host = ... // get from some method
host.orElseThrow[new IllegalArgumentException("Host is not provided")]
```

See the documentation about [lambda expressions](https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#lambdas).

(`->` is an operator in Xtend but it is not related to lambda expressions. See the documentation about [operators](https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#operators) and search for the *Pair Operator*.)

Comment: Thanks! This syntax works! Also, with the help of the link, another notation can also be used: host.orElseThrow( | new IllegalArgumentException("Host is not provided"))